# MongoDb insert date field without ISODate option

Tags: mongodb, date, date-format

I've to insert one date field in mongodb document without ISODate option. Whenever i insert date filed in mongodb it will automatically saved as ISODate format.. I dont want this behaviour.

For example,

```
"_id" : ObjectId("54992436a3baafe79eb67903"),
"name" : "example",
"insert_dt" : new Date("2014-12-26 12:36:00")
```

I need to be store in same above mentioned order.

Comment: You can always store date as string, but it may be not optimal in specific case.

Comment: Apart from string,is there any other ways we can store date as mentioned format?

Comment: `ISOdate` is a wrapper over `Date`. Why don't you want this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB, when you don't give timezones to your dates (as in your example), assumes that they're UTC (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), which is the only sane thing it can do (a date/time, without timezone info, means *nothing*).

What you *really* want to do is handle timezones in your program, because if you don't your program will behave erratically when you use it in winter/summer (depending on how DST works in your country), or when someone uses it from another country, or even in a different part of the US (yay for eastern/central/pacific time zones).

Fortunately, most programming languages come with facilities to deal with timezones, or have easily downloadable external libs to do that. As a Python dev my favorite is PyTZ (http://pytz.sourceforge.net/), and it looks like Node has a nice one at https://www.npmjs.com/package/timezone

Comment: My issue with Robomongo seems. When i tried to add one document with ISODate field But it shows wrong date value after saved.  db.testdate.insert({dt:ISODate("2014-12-26T23:30:00Z)})  while view the same document in Robomongo it shows wrong date.instead of 26th dec,It is added 5hrs and 30mins to the above date and displayed as 27th dec. {
    "_id" : ObjectId("54992436a3baafe79eb67903"),
    "name" : "example",
    "Billdate" : ISODate("2014-12-27T04:30:00.000+05:30")
}  How can I solve this issue?While query my document date value will not be matched.

Comment: That's normal (expected *and* desired) behavior. You should read up on how timezones work.

Comment: Is it normal? Then how can I query in robomongo , the documents which is inserted on  2014-12-26 at 23hrs?